# Pandas Drop Duplicates Between Groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which I would like to remove duplicates only across groups.

```html
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  2  Group 1
1  1  1  1  Group 2
2  1  1  1  Group 2
3  1  1  1  Group 2  
4  3  8  3  Group 2
5  3  8  3  Group 1
6  2  9  1  Group 2  
7  2  9  1  Group 1
8  1  0  2  Group 1
```

In the above dataframe I would want the following output:

```html
  A  B  C  D
0  1  0  2  Group 1
1  1  1  1  Group 2
2  1  1  1  Group 2
3  1  1  1  Group 2  
8  1  0  2  Group 1
```

For each cross group match (across group 1 and 2) if there is a paired match, remove it. Therefore, indices 4 and 5 were removed, as were 6 and 7. As you can see duplicates within a group are not dropped (indices 0,8 and 2,3).

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We can do `duplicated`

```
df=df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
   A  B  C       D
0  1  0  2  Group1
1  1  1  1  Group2
2  1  1  1  Group2
3  1  1  1  Group2
8  1  0  2  Group1
```

Update

```
df=df.groupby(list('ABC')).filter(lambda x : (x.nunique()==1).all())
   A  B  C       D
0  1  0  2  Group1
1  1  1  1  Group2
2  1  1  1  Group2
3  1  1  1  Group2
8  1  0  2  Group1
```

Comment: This seems to do something else. index `4` is dropped because it's not a duplicated, not because it's a duplicated of another row in the other group.

Answer (score 2):

Following your logic, we can check if per group of columns `A, B, C` the amount of unique values in column `D` is equal to `1`:

```
df[df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['D'].transform('nunique').eq(1)]

   A  B  C        D
0  1  0  2  Group 1
1  1  1  1  Group 2
2  1  1  1  Group 2
3  1  1  1  Group 2
8  1  0  2  Group 1
```